# Ordering by an intermediate table

Tags: ruby, sequel

Given these table structures and models, how do I go about implementing the "popular" method in the Ad class -- I'd simply like to return ads sorted by the number of hits on it.

```
require 'sequel'

db = Sequel.sqlite

db.create_table(:users){
    primary_key :id
}

db.create_table(:ads){
    primary_key :id
    foreign_key :user_id, :users
}

db.create_table(:hits){
    primary_key :id
}

db.create_join_table(ad_id: :ads, hit_id: :hits)


class User < Sequel::Model
    one_to_many :ads
end

class Hit < Sequel::Model
end

class Ad < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one :user
    many_to_many :hits

    def self.popular
        #return ads with most hits first
    end
end


User.create
Ad.create user: User[1]
Ad.create user: User[1]
Ad[1].add_hit Hit.create
Ad[2].add_hit Hit.create
Ad[2].add_hit Hit.create
Ad.popular
```

Comment: It's not obvious to me why Hit needs to be many-to-many to Ads. Can a Hit be associated with more than one Ad?

Comment: @Andrew -- The Hit table houses impression data, ip address, user id, date/time etc. To answer your question, no. it doesn't. An Ad has many hits/impressions. Clearly it's a one-to-many but the reason I chose many-to-many was to avoid having too many model specific Hit tables (ex: AdHit, ProductHit etc). Does it make sense?